# Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode" error in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, scikit-learn

Here is an my code, where I am trying to run this DBSCAN algorithm for my list of points which is in the coordinates matrix below. The matrix looks as follows:

```
[[43.285569, 5.350558], 
[48.728766, 2.369763], 
[48.82206, 2.325197], 
[48.82206, 2.325197], 
....................
[48.822879, 2.325046], 
[48.822943, 2.325099], 
[48.830726, 2.331268]]
```

However when I run the code I am getting the following error:

```
"UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if self._markerfacecolor != fc:"
```

Can anyone suggest why this may be happening? Thank you!

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import numpy
import csv


def plot_cluster(cluster, sample_matrix):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    f = lambda row: [float(x) for x in row]

    sample_matrix = map(f,sample_matrix)
    print sample_matrix
    sample_matrix = StandardScaler().fit_transform(sample_matrix)

    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(cluster.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[cluster.core_sample_indices_] = True
    labels = cluster.labels_

    # Black removed and is used for noise instead.
    unique_labels = set(labels)
    colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels)))
    for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
        if k == -1:
            # Black used for noise.
            col = 'k'

        class_member_mask = (labels == k)  # generator comprehension
        # X is your data matrix
        X = np.array(sample_matrix)

        xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]

        plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
                 markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

        xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
        plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
                 markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

    plt.ylim([0,10])
    plt.xlim([0,10])
#        plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
    plt.savefig('cluster.png')

dbscan_object = DBSCAN(3.0,4)

input = np.genfromtxt(open("dataset_import_noaddress.csv","rb"),delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
coordinates = np.delete(input, [0,1], 1)

result = dbscan_object.fit(coordinates)
print result.labels_

print 'plotting '
plot_cluster(result, coordinates)
```

Comment: It is telling you that you are not comparing unicode objects.

Comment: That's not an error but a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame DBSCAN when you have an error in your *drawing* logic.

Understand how to read the error *trace* and include it in your question. The information *where* the error happened is the single most important information!

So what is the "wrong" marker face color?

Maybe all you need to do is replace *all* occurences of `'k'` with a black color object (instead of a string) and the warning will go away.

Since your data are coordinates, you should also use haversine distance, not euclidean. Do *not* scale the data set! You are literally distorting your data. Stop recycling code you found on the internet, that you don't understand. If you don't understand what `StandardScaler` is, don't use it. Here, it is incorrect to use it.